# Поставить обработчик на изменение свойства stringValue в NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Нужно менять значение свойства при изменении пользователем текста в `NSTextField` компоненте. `NSTextField` создаётся программно. Свойство объявлено в контроллере так:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString* lineName;
-(void)setLineName:(NSString*)value {
    NSLog(@"%s", value);
    _lineName = value;
}
```

NSTextField создаётся в кодах и его свойство stringValue биндится к свойству контроллера lineName.

```
NSTextField* textField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
...
[self.bind:@"lineName" toObject:textField withKeyPath:@"stringValue" options:@{} ]
```

Получаю следующее поведение. Если пользователь вводит текст в `textField`, ничего не происходит. Если `textField` задать `stringValue` программно `(textField.stringValue = @"AAAAAAA")`, то биндинг срабатывает - вызывается сеттер свойства `stringValue`.

Подскажите, как обработать завершение ввода пользователем в NSTextField, созданный программно?

Comment: У Вас кастомный  NSWindow?

Comment: Может Вам надо переопределить метод - (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {} и вернуть YES; И назначен ли у вас делегат?

Comment: Делегат для textField не устанавливается

Comment: NSTextField используется как есть, но размещается на свой компонент наследник NSView.

Comment: Смотрите делегаты в документации для UITextField, не забывайте про установку delegate и datasource в контроллере для UITextField